# WHat object is passed into create_table block in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when you generate a model in rails, and it creates a skeleton migration file.

in has

```
create_table :model_names do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :address
  t.timestamps
end
```

What object is being passed in as t.

When  I read this part of the book I wondered what t was, but it never explained. Then later I learned in the `form_for` helper which passes an `|f|` into its block, that the f was a `FormBuilder` object, and this made me come here and ask. I mean, it obviously isn't important, but it bugs me when knowledge is missing.

Comment: hey we got famous! [but maybe this was there before us...](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the answer is `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition`
how do I know?

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      puts "the answer is: " + t.class.to_s
      t.string :foo

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I know this it just never occured to me to do it, guess it becomes second nature to do things like that when you have been using ROR for a while

Answer (score 1):

Playing with [pry](http://pry.github.com/) (or the ruby debugger) is a fun, easy way to explore.

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      binding.pry  
    end
  end
end
```

Things like the [apidock docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table) often provide answers in actual text. When they don't, viewing the source often leads to the answer in relatively short order (it does, in this case).